# On a certain prime structure.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is unknown whether there are infinite primes $p$ where $2p-1$ is also a prime.

Is it known there are only finitely many primes $p$ such that both $q$ and $2p-1$ are primes where $p-1=2aq$ for any fixed $a$?

That is $q$, $p=2aq+1$ and $2p-1=2(2aq+1)-1=4aq+1$ are all primes.

What is the density of such primes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the possibilities mod $3$.

EDIT: This was for the original question.  For the new question,  there seem to be infinitely many whenever $a$ is a multiple of $3$.  This would follow from Dickson's conjecture.  However, there is AFAIK no $a$ for which this has been proven.

For example, with $a=3$ we have $q$, $6q+1$ and $12q+1$ prime for $q = 3, 5, 13, 23, 61, 73, 83, 101, 103, 233, 271, 293, 311, 503, 601, 661, 751, 761, 773, 863, \ldots$.

Comment: I understand $q$ has to be mod $1,3$ or $9$.

Comment: $q=3$ gives $p=2q+1=7$ and $2p-1=2(2q+1)-1=4q+1=13$ are all primes.

Comment: @Turbo: now try $q > 3$.

Comment: @TonyK thank you  can $q$, $p=aq+1$ and $2aq+1$ be all primes for some fixed $a$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael could you please elaborate on dickson conjecture?

Comment: @RobertIsrael do you have information on density?

Comment: See [this page](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/DicksonsConjecture.html) on Dickson's conjecture.  That also has the conjectured asymptotics on the number of solutions.